# Apollo Server, Graphql - Must provide query string

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, serverless

Im not sure what im doing wrong here? I've been stuck now for soem time on getting my mutations to run with my apollo-server-lambda in my serverless setup, my queries works fine bu when i try to run a query like this:

```
{ "mutation": "{ signIn(username: \"SomeUser\", password: \"SomePassword\" ) { token } }" }
```

I just get the message: " Must provide query string." status 400.

I've set up my resolver like so:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: async (_, args, ctx) => User.load(args, ctx)
  },

  Mutation: {
    signIn: async (_, { username, password }, ctx) => Auth.signIn({ username, password }, ctx)
  }
};
```

For additional infor here is my typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    id: ID!,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    username: String,
    createdAt: String,
    role: String
  }

  type AuthToken {
    token: String
  }

  type Query {
    hello: String,
    users(id: Int): [User]
  }

  type Mutation {
    signIn(username: String!, password: String!): AuthToken!
  }
`;
```

I'm using postman to test my graphql endpoint and my content type is application/json

I dont know if any one here can tell me what im doing wrong, i tryed to move it all to Query resolver, and it works replace "mutation" with "query" then but it dosent make sens to me using the "query" here and i guess later on when i actually want to use the Mutation to mutate data i would need this to work anyway?

Can any one tell me where im wrong here?

**EDIT**

I installed: `graphql-playground-middleware-lambda` and set up the serverless setup with: https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground#as-serverless-handler and if i use Graphiql it works as intented, but im still interested if any one knows whats wrong with the json i send via postman?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When sending the request, your request body should be a properly-formatted JSON object, with a `query` property (and optionally, a `variables` property if including variables):

```
{
  "query": "<GraphQL Document>",
  "variables {},
}
```

This is the case whether the operation itself is a `query` or a `mutation`.

The actual value of the `query` property above must be a syntactically correct **document**, as outlined in the GraphQL [specification](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Language.Document). A document will typically consist of a single operation definition (either a `query` or a `mutation`) that includes all the requested fields for that operation. The document will also include fragments, if using any.

An operation definition looks like this:

```
OperationType [Name] [VariableDefinitions] [Directives] SelectionSet
```

So you could have a document like this:

```
mutation SomeMutation {
  signIn(username: "SomeUser", password: "SomePassword") {
    token
  }
}
```

Here, the **type** of the operation is `mutation`, the **name** is `SomeMutation` and everything between the outermost set of curly brackets is the **selection set**. If you had any variables, their types would be declared in parentheses before the selection set.

The operation name is optional, but it's helpful to include it for debugging purposes on the backend. Technically, the operation type can be omitted as well, in which case GraphQL simply assumes the type is a query. For example, this is still a valid document:

```
{
  users {
    id
  }
}
```

and is equivalent to

```
query SomeName {
  users {
    id
  }
}
```

The former is referred to as **query shorthand**. Obviously, this cannot be used for mutations, so mutations must always explicitly state their operation type. A complete example:

```
{
  "query": "mutation SomeName ($username: String!, $password: String!) { signIn(username: $username, password: $password) { token } }",
  "variables {
    "username": "SomeUser",
    "password": "SomePassword"
  },
}
```

Comment: You sir wins my internet award of the day today! Thank you for cutting it in to something i could understand! :)