# Python Graphene Mutation is not works

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I'm new in Graphql and Python too.

So while I was develop a lil project, I just had this problem with mutation:

```
class User(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID(required=False)
    username = graphene.String()
    last_login = graphene.DateTime(required=False)

class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        username = graphene.String()

    user = graphene.Field(User)

    def mutate(self, info, username):
        user = User(username=username)
        return CreateUser(user=user)

class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(mutation=Mutations)
```

And I'm making this call in Postman:

> {
>       "mutation": "{ createUser(username: 'User test') { user { username } } }" }

My Header:

> Content-Type:application/json

And my response is **null**

I don't know if my problem is the implementation, or my call.

------------------- EDITED -----------------------------
I just modify somethings in my code, now I have a query, and it works and I implement a simple request direct in code, and it works

I just did it:

```
import graphene
import json
from datetime import datetime

class User(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID(required=False)
    username = graphene.String()
    last_login = graphene.DateTime(required=False)


def __populate_users__():
    return [
        User(username='User1 teste', last_login=datetime.now()),
        User(username='User2 teste', last_login=datetime.now()),
        User(username='User3 teste', last_login=datetime.now())
    ]


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    users = graphene.List(User, first=graphene.Int())
    all_users = graphene.List(User)

    def resolve_users(self, info, first):
        return __populate_users__()[:first]

    def resolve_all_users(self, info):
        return __populate_users__()

class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        username = graphene.String()

    user = graphene.Field(User)

    def mutate(self, info, username):
        print "TESTE"
        user = User(username=username)
        return CreateUser(user=user)

class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutations)

# IT WORKS!!!
result = schema.execute(
    '''
    mutation {
        createUser(username: "User test") {
            user {
                username
            }
        }
    }
    '''
)

items = dict(result.data.items())
print(json.dumps(items))
```

So when I call my query in Postman, it works too:

> {
>       "query": "{ allUsers {username  lastLogin}  }" }

And headers:

> Content-Type:application/json

I cannot understand why query works and mutation not works in Postman.

Comment: Can't speak to your schema since I'm not that familiar with graphene, but your request is definitely not formatted correctly. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081186/6024220) for full details. If that solves your issue, let's close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: It's not easy to use Postman with graphene.  You should set up graphiql and use that instead of Postman.  Then you can quickly determine whether the problem is your mutation query or if it is how you are calling postman.

Comment: Based on my answer on Postman set up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185188/graphene-django-must-provide-query-string/44509102#44509102 it looks like you need to add variables and operationName

Comment: Thanks, for the answers, but I cannot resolve it yet, so I just edited my code with more information.